# Is it necessary to use only the same Mohel?

Tags: brit-milah

Recently I was told that when one makes a Bris they should use the same Mohel they used for the older child. Is there a source for this? What is the reason?

Comment: Maybe the same reason the same kohen takes the levi's aliyah in the absence of a levi — they might think he is invalid.

Comment: @ba I had the same thought - you wouldn't want to imply that you were dissatisfied with the mohel's work!

Comment: I have had the same thought, however I can think of a difference, as it is not happening at the same time. In addition if that is the reason is there a source that implies that?

Comment: Whoever told you this did they give some sort of basis for it?

Comment: @Yehoshua: no - hence the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rabbi Yitzchok Sender Kuperman Z"L in a lengthy piece in [HaPardes #68 Vol 3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=12706&st=&pgnum=14) concludes that there is really no problem switching and using a different Mohel if you have any reason. Reasons can include that the new Mohel is better, a relative, a Talmid Chacham, you owe him a favor, etc.

Comment: But not without a reason?

Comment: However any reason seems sufficient.

Comment: Doesn't "the new Mohel is better" kind of negate the concern raised in the question and serve, effectively, as "no reason"?

Comment: It seems to me that the concern raised is of no concern to Rabbi Yitzchok Sender Kuperman Z"L